# CSS transformOrigin property not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an svg with some regions that need to be zoomed when I click. I used the css transformOrigin property and set it to the coordinates of my mouse click So i can scale the image around this point. Instead when the svg scales, it is offset by few pixels from the point where I clicked. Is there something I missing here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('g').click(function(e){
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        $('g.states').css({'transformOrigin': x+' '+y});
        $('g.states').transition({scale: "2"});     
    })
    $('#zoomout').click(function(){
        $('g.states').transition({scale:"1"});
    })
});
```

the `.transition` method is part of the [jquery transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) library.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Where is your codE?

Comment: place some code over here